# UITableView [self.navigationController pushViewController:Page1 animated:YES]; method not working

Tags: iphone, uitableview, pushviewcontroller, addsubview

Well here is my method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath
{
if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0){
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:Page1 animated:YES];
}
if (indexPath.row == 1 && indexPath.section == 0){
    [self.view addSubview:Page2.view];  
}
```

well I changed the method from

```
[self.view addSubview:Page1.view]; //this works perfectly however as soon as I change to this
[self.navigationController pushViewController:Page1 animated:YES];// this does not work
```

The method is being called,  I have added NSLog's before and after and the both were called. However, when called this method only makes the cell turn blue (however this happens with both the addSubview and pushViewController methods) 
The view I am pushing to is just a normal UIView.
I can add the views I need, but they are not animated (because I'm using the addSubview method)

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Are you inside a UINavigationController? Is self.navigationController = nil maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you not setup proper to your navigation controller,you can implement this in your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method in appdelegate.m file

```
self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];

[self.navController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];

[self.window addSubview:self.navController.view];
```

Comment: My method says that Property 'viewController' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate' My app was made in xcode4.2.1 and is a tab based application, if that means anything, and would explain why the code doesnt work. within those 4 lines, I received 8 errors.

Answer (score 0):

Better set `navController` as `rootViewController` of `window`:

```
self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
[self.navController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];

self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
```

Comment: My method says that Property 'viewController' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate' My app was made in xcode4.2.1 and is a tab based application, if that means anything, and would explain why the code doesnt work. within those 4 lines, I received 8 errors.

Comment: your controller where tableview is doesnot have navigationcontroller as parent view controller. By default every view controller's view has navigationController property but cannot push view controller unless u have addded navigation controller to your window hierarchy..

Answer (score 0):

Because , User edit the question, So I am giving answer again. If you wants tabBar with NavigationController

IN AppDelegate.h  Define `UINavigationController *navController;` and make property and synthesize it in appDelegate.m.

import your all ViewController classes in AppDelegate.m

like

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Preview.h"
#import "Export.h"
#import "Settings.h"
#import "More.h"



- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.


tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.delegate=self;

//Adding Search,Nearby,Map,AboutUs,Favorites Tabs to tabBarController
ViewController * search = [[ViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *searchNav = [[UINavigationController alloc]        initWithRootViewController:search];

Preview* nearby = [[Preview alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nearbyNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nearby];

Export* map = [[Export alloc] init];
UINavigationController *mapNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:map];

Settings* aboutUs = [[Settings alloc] init];
UINavigationController *aboutUsNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:aboutUs];

More* favorites = [[More alloc] init];
UINavigationController *favoritesNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:favorites];

NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:searchNav,nearbyNav,mapNav,aboutUsNav,favoritesNav, nil];

tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;

[self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];

//  self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
//  self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;

}
```

May be this help you.

Answer (score 0):

the viewController page1 when you have added to the the `self.view`  then how can it get animated when you are pushing because it is already on the top of view from

```
[self.view addSubview:Page1.view]; //this works perfectly however as soon as I change to this
[self.navigationController pushViewController:Page1 animated:YES];// this does not work
```

Hope that helps